Как обратиться к элементу в двумерном классе в c#?
class Rastvorimost
{
    public class NH4 { short F = 0, Cl = 0, Br = 0, I = 0, S = 0, SO3 = 0, SO4 = 0, NO3 = 0, NO2 = 0, PO4 = 0, CO3 = 0, SiO3 = 0; }
    public class Li { short F = 0, Cl = 0, Br = 0, I = 0, S = 0, SO3 = 0, SO4 = 0, NO3 = 0, NO2 = 0, PO4 = 0, CO3 = 0, SiO3 = 0; }
    public class Na { short F = 0, Cl = 0, Br = 0, I = 0, S = 0, SO3 = 0, SO4 = 0, NO3 = 0, NO2 = 0, PO4 = 0, CO3 = 0, SiO3 = 0; }
    public class Mg { short F = 0, Cl = 0, Br = 0, I = 0, S = 0, SO3 = 0, SO4 = 0, NO3 = 0, NO2 = 0, PO4 = 0, CO3 = 0, SiO3 = 0; }
    public class Al { short F = 0, Cl = 0, Br = 0, I = 0, S = 0, SO3 = 0, SO4 = 0, NO3 = 0, NO2 = 0, PO4 = 0, CO3 = 0, SiO3 = 0; }
    public class Ca { short F = 0, Cl = 0, Br = 0, I = 0, S = 0, SO3 = 0, SO4 = 0, NO3 = 0, NO2 = 0, PO4 = 0, CO3 = 0, SiO3 = 0; }
    public class Cr { short F = 0, Cl = 0, Br = 0, I = 0, S = 0, SO3 = 0, SO4 = 0, NO3 = 0, NO2 = 0, PO4 = 0, CO3 = 0, SiO3 = 0; }
    public class Mn { short F = 0, Cl = 0, Br = 0, I = 0, S = 0, SO3 = 0, SO4 = 0, NO3 = 0, NO2 = 0, PO4 = 0, CO3 = 0, SiO3 = 0; }
    public class Fe { short F = 0, Cl = 0, Br = 0, I = 0, S = 0, SO3 = 0, SO4 = 0, NO3 = 0, NO2 = 0, PO4 = 0, CO3 = 0, SiO3 = 0; }
    public class Co { short F = 0, Cl = 0, Br = 0, I = 0, S = 0, SO3 = 0, SO4 = 0, NO3 = 0, NO2 = 0, PO4 = 0, CO3 = 0, SiO3 = 0; }
    public class Ni { short F = 0, Cl = 0, Br = 0, I = 0, S = 0, SO3 = 0, SO4 = 0, NO3 = 0, NO2 = 0, PO4 = 0, CO3 = 0, SiO3 = 0; }
    public class Cu { short F = 0, Cl = 0, Br = 0, I = 0, S = 0, SO3 = 0, SO4 = 0, NO3 = 0, NO2 = 0, PO4 = 0, CO3 = 0, SiO3 = 0; }
    public class Zn { short F = 0, Cl = 0, Br = 0, I = 0, S = 0, SO3 = 0, SO4 = 0, NO3 = 0, NO2 = 0, PO4 = 0, CO3 = 0, SiO3 = 0; }
    public class Sr { short F = 0, Cl = 0, Br = 0, I = 0, S = 0, SO3 = 0, SO4 = 0, NO3 = 0, NO2 = 0, PO4 = 0, CO3 = 0, SiO3 = 0; }
    public class Pd { short F = 0, Cl = 0, Br = 0, I = 0, S = 0, SO3 = 0, SO4 = 0, NO3 = 0, NO2 = 0, PO4 = 0, CO3 = 0, SiO3 = 0; }
    public class Ag { short F = 0, Cl = 0, Br = 0, I = 0, S = 0, SO3 = 0, SO4 = 0, NO3 = 0, NO2 = 0, PO4 = 0, CO3 = 0, SiO3 = 0; }
    public class Sn { short F = 0, Cl = 0, Br = 0, I = 0, S = 0, SO3 = 0, SO4 = 0, NO3 = 0, NO2 = 0, PO4 = 0, CO3 = 0, SiO3 = 0; }
    public class Ba { short F = 0, Cl = 0, Br = 0, I = 0, S = 0, SO3 = 0, SO4 = 0, NO3 = 0, NO2 = 0, PO4 = 0, CO3 = 0, SiO3 = 0; }
    public class Hg { short F = 0, Cl = 0, Br = 0, I = 0, S = 0, SO3 = 0, SO4 = 0, NO3 = 0, NO2 = 0, PO4 = 0, CO3 = 0, SiO3 = 0; }
    public class Pb { short F = 0, Cl = 0, Br = 0, I = 0, S = 0, SO3 = 0, SO4 = 0, NO3 = 0, NO2 = 0, PO4 = 0, CO3 = 0, SiO3 = 0; }
    public class K { short F = 0, Cl = 0, Br = 0, I = 0, S = 0, SO3 = 0, SO4 = 0, NO3 = 0, NO2 = 0, PO4 = 0, CO3 = 0, SiO3 = 0; }

};

namespace Himiya1
{
    public partial class HimicheskiyKalkulyatorByMaksimBorodkin : Form
    {
        public HimicheskiyKalkulyatorByMaksimBorodkin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            char[] massVvod0 = new char[100];
            string[] massVvod1 = new string[100];


            string kationVvod0, kationVvod1, anionVvod0, anionVvod1,
                classVvod0, classVvod1;

            int indexKationVvod0, indexKationVvod1, indexAnionVvod0, indexAnionVvod1,//индексы ионов в водимых данных
                postIndexKationVvod0, postIndexKationVvod1, postIndexAnionVvod0, postIndexAnionVvod1,//Индексы иодов в выводимом уравнении
                index0, index1, index2, index3;


            string vvod0 = textBox1.Text;
            string vvod1 = textBox2.Text;
            massVvod0 = vvod0.ToCharArray();
            textBox2.Text = Rastvorimost //Вот здесь я не понял как обратиться


            //thread.sleep(100000);//ожидание в мс
            //close();
        }
    }
}


причем тут двумерный массив? Обратиться к чему нужно?

Nested Types

@Grundy кажется, человек пришёл из мира динамической типизации, и пока не понимает, что к чему. Вложенные типы тут вряд-ли помогут.

Этот вопрос уже не актуален, можете пожалуйста написать пример двумерного словаря(Dictionary), с ключами в виде строк как к самим "подсловарям" так и к самим элементам (они будут уже типа byte). Мне всё это нужно для реализации проги по химии(так что словарь идеально подходит по задачу)
